# Pairs like quot/tot and quantum/tantum

Tags: word-comparison, language-evolution, pronouns

There seem to be a lot of pairs of words in Latin where a "question" starts with *qu-* and the corresponding "answer" by *t-*.
For example: *quot/tot*, *quantum/tantum*, *qualis/talis*, *quotiens/totiens*.
The pattern is pretty clear, although there are some holes (e.g. *quis* and *quando* but no **tis* or **tando*).

What is the origin of this *qu-/t-* duality?
Does it go all the way to PIE, or is it an Italic invention?
Do we know the origin of the elements *qu-* and *t-*?

Comment: Is `word-comparison` the right tag for this?

Comment: @Draconis I don't know. I'm kind of comparing pairs of pronouns, but I don't mind if the tag is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern seems to go all the way back to Proto-Indo-European.

As Sumelic pointed out in a comment, we actually see this same alternation in English: when~then, what~that, where~there, and so on. This wh~th alternation comes from older Germanic *hʷ~*þ(*), which comes from PIE *kʷ~*t by Grimm's Law (which weakened stops into fricatives at the beginning of words).

(*) þ ("thorn") was probably pronounced like English "th" in "thin", IPA /θ/

It seems like the former ones come from PIE **kʷi-*/*kʷe-*/*kʷo-*, the interrogative-indefinite pronoun (surviving as *quis* in Latin and *tís* in Ancient Greek); the latter ones come from PIE **to-*, the neuter demonstrative pronoun (the second half of *iste* in Latin, the definite article *tó* in Greek).

Various suffixes were added to derive specific meanings, like "which time" or "which quantity", and the forms with these suffixes turned into the *qu-*~*t-* pairs. It's not always clear what these suffixes *were*; for example, the second half of *quālis*~*tālis* can only be guessed at. But the roots themselves seem clear.